# Deleting Database and Its Log file

Tags: log-files

I have a sql server running on a desktop and it has used up the disk space on C. I dont have historical data in the tables. SQL is used to process text files to then be loaded into TM1. All I need is the tables,views structure,etc. As a drastic measure, can I stop the service, delete the Database and its log files and recreate the tables and views with the same names and restart the service? will that reduce the log files to 0?
I plan to do a regular back up of the log files after that.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better to carry out the following process:

1. Set the database logging mode to simple
2. Set the 'auto shrink' database option
3. Shrink the log file with
   `use <your_database>`
   `DBCC SHRINKFILE(2, 256)`
   NB: this assumes your log file is file number 2 (which is typically the case).

You may need to run the `DBCC` command a couple of times to have the desired effect.

Comment: I have read so many posts not to shrink and that wont reduce the size of log files...

Comment: There are options for DBCC which only apply to the Data files, not the case for the command above.  Also, note that I include instruction to set the logging mode to `simple` first - without this (or a backup of the transaction log, which doesn't apply in your use-case) then you're right, but with the log in `simple` mode, this will shrink the file on-disk - I've done this many times!

Comment: This may be a silly question, what does 256 indicate?

Comment: its ok, i figured it out, its 256 MB...Thanks I will try your suggestion tomorrow!